# Running regular Migrate in Cron leads to duplicate nodes

Tags: 6, nodes, cron, importing-exporting, migrations

Related: [Schedule Migrate to import XML data regularly](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/57779/schedule-migrate-to-import-xml-data-regularly)

I am getting duplicate nodes every time I try to do a rollback/update. Is it because they are triggered when users visit the page (instead of me), or does it have something to do with my MigrateSQLMap?

**EDIT**
I have come up with a sort of workaround for this: I need to, instead of doing a rollback/migrate, I need to do something like what I outlined below. I just don't know how to put it together.
Each source item in the XML has an ID, which I have/will import ad the field_sourceid in the node.

Here are the steps I need:

1. Grab all source IDs of the nodes and source IDs of the XML
2. Check them against each other:

   - If the node's SourceID isn't matched in the XML, that means that node is expired. Delete it.
   - If there is a Source ID in the XML but nothing matching in the nodes, then this is a new node. Import it.
   - If the SourceID exists in the XML, we have a current node. Update it.

It was my understanding that you could not declare prepareRow() when you use XMLMigration. What do I do then? It seems like I need something like that here.